# How do we understand the results of $1/N$ or $\epsilon$ expansion beyond leading orders?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, approximations, ising-model, critical-phenomena, large-n

When we do $1/N$ expansions in, say, 2+1$D$ $O(N)$ models and try to extract all kinds of critical exponents from it, we get the following results for the scaling dimensions of various operators up to order $1/N^2$ (Here $\phi$ is the vector field, $S$ is the scalar operator and $T$ is the symmetric traceless operator)
$$\Delta_\phi = 0.5+\frac{0.135}{N}-\frac{0.097}{N^2}$$
$$\Delta_S = 2-\frac{1.081}{N}-\frac{3.048}{N^2}$$
$$\Delta_T = 1+\frac{1.081}{N}-\frac{0.195}{N^2}$$
We see that especially for $S$ the expansion is not very good since the coefficient for $1/N^2$ is very big and it will not give us a sensible scaling dimensions. Similar problems will be encountered in epsilon expansions. How do we make sense of these results beyond leading orders?

Comment: One can use suitable resummation methods. E.g. the simple fact that for small $N$ an expansion in positive powers of $N$ also exists (even if these expansion coefficients are not known), means that you can re-expand the series by putting $\frac{1}{N} = \lambda \frac{u}{1-u}$ where $\lambda$ is an arbitrary parameter that can be optimized by choosing it such that the last known term of the expansion becomes zero.

Comment: As shown by Zinn-Justin, this method yields rapidly converging approximations in the sense that with more and more terms and summing till the last term set to zero using $\lambda$, makes the error in the approximation smaller and smaller.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: You can check out https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0675 and references in there.